# What could I put to session in rails / web-development?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, session

I am trying to figure possible use cases for sessions in Rails and web-development in general.

According these articles: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#session, http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#session session cannot hold lot of information (4 kb per user) and that information should be kept safe.

I know that sessions are useful place to store cookies after authentication to allow users have state in stateless web. What other use cases there might be?

Comment: Why downvote? May I get some feedback  to improve this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your question is being downvoted because it is quite broad. Rails sessions and cookies can be used for a variety of things. In addition to authentication sessions can store the page where the user last visited. This way when they login the user can be taken back to the page they were trying to access before they were redirected to a login.

Do you have a more specific question about rails sessions?

Comment: That is a good point, the question should be more specific. Maybe this kind of broad reflections do not fit to Q&A forum. I was maybe looking for somekind of list of things that developers are using session for. Thanks for example!